# put output into a variable

Tags: shell, unix, terminal

The following works if I type it in a shell window. But how do I get the result into a variable?

```
date -j -v+1m -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s"
```

Comment: Please state the type of shell. Syntax will vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `command substitution $(..)` and capture the output in a variable

```
var=$(date -j -v+1m -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s")
echo $var
```

#### Note: Not tested and as stated in the comments, the syntax may vary.